# Add a column in the middle of a row from a .csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

Hello I have a python script which changes a timestamp column in a .csv file from dot notation to "date time TSQL" notation:

One row looks like this before executing the code:

```
send,2007.10.04.10.11.11.669,Server,Data,Client,TYPE=STP,Length=329,Cnt=11
```

after executing the code it looks like this:

```
send,2007-10-04 10:11:11.669,Server,Data,Client,TYPE=STP,Length=329,Cnt=11
```

I want to append the same time in the new format after the first time column, that it looks like this:

```
send,2007-10-04 10:11:11.669,2007-10-04 10:11:11.669,Server,Data,Client,TYPE=STP,Length=329,Cnt=11
```

Here is the Script:

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open("ActualTrace_01 - short2Times.csv", "rb"))
output = csv.writer(open("GermanygoalInputFormatActualTrace_01 - short.csv", "wb"))

for row in cr:    
    dateTimeContentsSend = row[1].split(".")
    finishSend = dateTimeContentsSend[0] + "-" + dateTimeContentsSend[1] + "-" + dateTimeContentsSend[2] + " " + dateTimeContentsSend[3] + ":" 
    finishSend+= dateTimeContentsSend[4] + ":" + dateTimeContentsSend[5] + "." + dateTimeContentsSend[6]

    row[1] = finishSend
    output.writerow(row)
```

All Threads here were not useful and if you just say row[1] = finishSend + "," + finishSend
it makes it in row[1] with quotes like this

```
send,"2007-10-04 10:11:11.669,2007-10-04 10:11:11.684",Server,Data,Client,TYPE=STP,Length=329,Cnt=11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after (just after `row[1] = finishSend`)?

```
row.insert(2, row[1])
```